# erro de execução do MySQL - XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost

Estou tentando criar um *localhost* com o *xampp*, mas o *MySQL* não inicia. Dá este *log*

**mysql_error.log:**

> ```
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
> Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1835037
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
> ```

Answer (score -1):

O log que você colou não é referente à sua tentativa de iniciar o XAMPP. Essa parte aí é de 2015, e provavelmente é da primeira inicialização do XAMPP, enquanto ele estava sendo preparado pra ser distribuído (pelo que pesquisei, tem esse log exatamente em vários outros sites, ex: https://jira.mariadb.org/secure/attachment/43238/mysql_error.log).

Você precisa procurar no final do log as linhas mais recentes e corrigir a sua postagem. Se possível inclua também a tela do XAMPP.